# How to get immediate Visual Studio 2012 javascript debugging when attaching to IE10?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

When I start a web application with VS2012 in **debug mode**, and the javascript in the page raises an exception this happens:

1. VS - debug (F5)
2. IE10 opens and the source file with the error line is displayed quite in a second

perfect. but when I **run** the application:

1. Ctrl-F5
2. IE dispays **"Webpage Error"** dialog:

   Do you want to debug this web page?
   checkbox  Do not show this message again
   checkbox Use the built in script debugger in IE.
3. Click Yes
4. In the background (!) the **Machine Debugger Manager** pops up with the only option to say "ok".
5. Click Ok
6. Wait wait wait ... a minute later ...
7. **Visual Studio JIT Debugger:**
    An unhandled exception ..... occured. Possible Debuggers:
    New instance VS 2010
    New instance VS 2012
    MyProject (default) VS 2012
8. Select my project
9. Yes
10. The editor opens at the line with the error.

**What can I do to get immediate attaching and debugging to VS 2012 without any dialogs and minutes of waiting time (on a very fast machine)?**